# Adding a row after a particular row with slide down effect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to design a tree like table structure, so that clicking on a particular row it will slide down and add the new rows below to that. (Just designing Category and Sub category structure.)

I am able to append rows after a particular row but not able to add any effect to that.

```
$.post("quoteConversionsByCategory.cfm",
{   
    action:1,
    categoryID:categoryID
},
function(response){
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
     $.each(jsonResponse.DATA, function(i){
        var newData = $("<tr class='subcategoryrow' rel="+ jsonResponse.DATA[i][0] +" id=category"+ jsonResponse.DATA[i][0] +" parentID="+categoryID+" ><td colspan='1'>"+jsonResponse.DATA[i][1]+"</td></tr>");
        $("#category" + categoryID).after( newData ).fadeIn('slow');;   
    });
});
```

I am dynamically generating the rows(subcategories) and appending after a particular row (Category) . How to add the effect like fade or slide here while adding the new rows ?

Comment: I think you have to call `.hide()` before the `.after()` call

Answer (score 1):

The key here is you can't do any animations until something is already in the DOM.

So when you put your `newData` `.after()` the row, it inserts it and **then** animates it, which is not the behavior you want.

What you can do is add a class or style to any row you're adding that hides it via CSS - a la:

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Then, when you've finished adding it to the DOM, do your `.slideDown` or `.fadeIn`.

*You may also be able to call `.hide()` on the element before inserting it, but I'm not sure about that, so I won't recommend it without testing*